# PowerShell can create a Shortcut without name

Tags: powershell

Is it intentional that it is possible to create a shortcut without a name?
(Via GUI it is not possible)

[image]

I am not able to set a hotkey at an url shortcut while it is possible via the GUI. Is that a bug or intentional?

The code is basically the same as in [New-Shortcut](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-Shortcut-4d6fb3d8)

The console output is:

```
FullName         : C:\Stuff\.lnk    
Arguments        :
Description      :
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
WindowStyle      : 0
WorkingDirectory :
```

This is my function:

```
function New-Shortcut {
param 
(
    # Full path of the shortcut
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $FullPath,
    # Path to the target
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $TargetPath,
    # Arguments for the shortcut
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $Arguments = $null,
    # Description if needed
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $Description = $null,
    # Hotkey if needed
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $HotKey = $null,
    # Working directory if it differs from the shortcut directory
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $WorkingDirectory = $null,
    # Windows style (minimized, maximized, ...)
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int] $WindowStyle = $null,
    # Path to an icon if needed
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $IconPath = $null,
    # Run as admin configuration
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch] $RunAsAdmin  = $null
)

Write-Debug "Check if '$FullPath' is valid ([character]:[\[character/digit]+]* + [.lnk | .url]."
if (!($FullPath.Extension -match "(\.lnk|\.url)"))
{
    Write-Debug "'$FullPath' is no valid 'lnk' or 'url' shortcut."
    Write-Error -Message "'$FullPath' not valid (no valid shortcut type)." -Category InvalidArgument `
                -CategoryTargetName $FullPath -CategoryTargetType $FullPath.GetType() `
                -ErrorId "NoValidShortcutPath" -ErrorAction Stop
}
Write-Debug "'$FullPath' is a valid 'lnk' or 'url' shortcut."

# Define Shortcut Properties
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($FullPath)

$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath

# Create directory for shortcut if it not exist
if(!(Test-Path $FullPath.Directory))
{
    Write-Verbose ("Directory '{0}' does not exist, creating it..." -f $FullPath.Directory)
    New-Item -Path $FullPath.Directory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

if ($FullPath.Extension -eq ".url")
{
    Write-Verbose "Creating new shortcut '$FullPath' pointing at '$TargetPath'."
    $Shortcut.Save()
    Write-Debug "Shortcut '$FullPath' pointing at '$TargetPath' created!"
    return $Shortcut
}

$Shortcut.Arguments = $Arguments
$Shortcut.Description = $Description
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $WorkingDirectory
$Shortcut.WindowStyle = $WindowStyle
$Shortcut.HotKey = $HotKey

If ($IconPath)
{
    Write-Debug "Set icon to path '$IconPath'..."
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = $IconPath 
    Write-Debug "Icon path set."
}

Write-Verbose "Creating new shortcut '$FullPath' pointing at '$TargetPath'."
$Shortcut.Save()
Write-Debug "Shortcut '$FullPath' pointing at '$TargetPath' created!"

if ($RunAsAdmin)
{
    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FullPath)
    $bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20 #set byte 21 (0x15) bit 6 (0x20) ON
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FullPath, $bytes)
}

return $Shortcut
}
```

At least i want to have my first question well posted.

Here is my unit test, which is adapted to the situation that i can create a shortcut without name:

```
New-Shortcut -FullPath "C:\tmp\.lnk" -TargetPath "explorer.exe" -Verbose | 
            Should be $true #Should throw "'$invalidPath' not valid (no valid shortcut type)."
            #Test-Path $invalidPathIsNotInvalid | Should Be $false
```

Because of my test i came into the struggle i tried to explain here. But as LotPings said, it seems like the name of the shortcut is ".lnk", which is unusual but valid.

Seems like it already answered my question :)

Comment: Presumably you don't show extensions, so the name most likely is `.lnk` why do you present a gui picture insteaad of console text output?

Comment: I thought it would be helpful ;) console text output is:
FullName         : C:\Stuff\.lnk
Arguments        :
Description      :
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
WindowStyle      : 0
WorkingDirectory :

Comment: So the name is the extension, unususal but valid. Please [edit] your question to contain additional information - don't put into comments.

Comment: Your question is quite vague and contains no actual code so we don't know what, or how, you are trying to do. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!). I would recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). These will help you figure out what your question is missing so you can update your question and get an answer that will help you.